# Catch alert() thrown from iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Is it possible to detect when an iframe containing an external website fires an alert() dialogue?

I have an iframe with an external website and I can send query parameters in the URL, but if the query doesn't return results, the page loads a generic page and fires an alert that it didn't find the query. I don't have access to the iframe source, so I'm trying to catch it and leave a message on the page above the iframe that the source is generic (or something).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) prevents you from interacting with the other domains contents.

So the answer is no you can not detect it unless you have control of the other domain.